# How can I call the x:Name from another xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

1.Code from another xaml page.

```
<Frame x:Name="coc1Lock" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="2" BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0.95"> <!--COC1 Lock-->
                <Image Source="lock0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Lock_Tap"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            </Frame>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? If people know what you're asking, you're more likely to get good feedback.

Comment: Please, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the page which element has to be called assign this element to some global variable, after the `InitializeComponent();` line, ex:

```
Globals.Instance.CocLock = coc1Lock;
```

then everywhere in the app you have access to it via `Globals.Instance.CocLock`.

Comment: How can I do that??